# Django Rest Framework present serializer fields in specific order

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

regarding DRF Serializers, I know that fields are returned as OrderedDict but I have below issue because of inheritance from other serializer class.

```
class SerializerA(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

class SerializerB(SerializerA):
    surname = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()
```

So, serializer A will return things in below order.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
}

and serializer B will return this.
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo",
    "surname: "Bar",
    "age": 15
}
```

However, what I want is that to return Serializer B as written below (or a different order)

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "surname: "Bar",
    "age": 15
    "id": 1,
}
```

What do you think about best way to do this?

Comment: Totally understood the issue, but I strongly recommend not being dependant on the order of data in a serializer. maybe if you explain the need for order, I can help you overcome the problem with another solution.

Comment: Order in json (serialized) objects don't really matter. Mostly never. Because wherever this data will be used, will definitely have all the fields available (regardless of order). However json lists can be ordered